# How can I get certain letters to be aligned straight above each other?

Tags: html, css

So for a school project, I'd like to get this [Word clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDmTf.png) digitalized on a website. However, I can't get the letters on each line to be spaced in a way that they're exactly above each other. Thin letters like the 'i' and 'l' cause the lines to each have a different width.

I have currently placed all the words in span tags so I can independently give them js and CSS properties.

Is there a better way to do this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
 font-family: Open Sans;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #444444;
}

.main {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 470px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 75px auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

      <div class="row1">
        <span>i t</span>
        <span>l</span>
        <span>i s</span>
        <span>a s t i m e</span>
      </div>

      <div class="row2">
        <span>a </span>
        <span>c</span>
        <span>q u a r t e r</span>
        <span>d c</span>
      </div>

      <div class="row3">
        <span>t w e n t y</span>
        <span>f i v e</span>
        <span>x</span>
      </div>

      <div class="row4">
        <span>h a l f</span>
        <span>s</span>
        <span>t e n</span>
        <span>f</span>
        <span>t o</span>
      </div>

      <div class="row5">
        <span>p a s t</span>
        <span>e r u</span>
        <span>n i n e</span>
      </div>

      <div class="row6">
        <span>o n e </span>
        <span>s i x</span>
        <span>t h r e e</span>
      </div>

      <div class="row7">
        <span>f o u r</span>
        <span>f i v e</span>
        <span>t w o</span>
      </div>

      <div class="row8">
        <span>e i g h t</span>
        <span>e l e v e n</span>
      </div>

      <div class="row9">
        <span>s e v e n</span>
        <span>t w e l v e</span>
      </div>

      <div class="row10">
        <span>t e n</span>
        <span>s e</span>
        <span>o' c l o c k</span>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: use a monospace font ?

Comment: Yes that works!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use monospaced font. Monospaced fonts have fixed width for all letters.

Some of monospaced fonts available on Google fonts(https://fonts.google.com/):

1. IBM Plex Mono
2. Roboto Mono
3. Source Code Pro
4. Ubuntu Mono

   I used **monospace font-family** in below example.

   ```
   font-family:monospace
   ```

Here is the example JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/srijan1709/xfLuw3pv/2/